# try to get webric to work

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, vps, puma

I been trying for weeks now to get webric [Webric](https://github.com/jamez01/WebRic) to work and been unable to.
The error shown in the log is

```
Started GET "/config.json" for 82.2.58.4 at 2016-10-26 23:19:50 +0200

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/config.json"):

actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:53:in `call'
web-console (3.3.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:131:in `call_app'
web-console (3.3.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:20:in `block in call'
web-console (3.3.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `catch'
web-console (3.3.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:31:in `call'
railties (5.0.0.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:36:in `call_app'
railties (5.0.0.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `block in call'
activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:70:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:70:in `tagged'
railties (5.0.0.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `call'
sprockets-rails (3.2.0) lib/sprockets/rails/quiet_assets.rb:13:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:24:in `call'
rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/method_override.rb:22:in `call'
rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:136:in `call'
rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'
railties (5.0.0.1) lib/rails/engine.rb:522:in `call'
puma (3.6.0) lib/puma/configuration.rb:225:in `call'
puma (3.6.0) lib/puma/server.rb:578:in `handle_request'
puma (3.6.0) lib/puma/server.rb:415:in `process_client'
puma (3.6.0) lib/puma/server.rb:275:in `block in run'
puma (3.6.0) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:116:in `block in spawn_thread'
  Rendering /home/chat/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.text.erb
  Rendering /home/chat/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.text.erb
  Rendered /home/chat/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.text.erb (0.8ms)
  Rendered /home/chat/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.text.erb (7.9ms)
```

Can any help me please Many Thanks

Comment: Can anyone help me please?
Thanks